# Prevent help page folds from being lost

Tags: folding, help-system

When I open a help page, create a manual fold, set `bufhidden=hide` and `buflisted`, then navigate away from that page, the fold is not restored upon returning.

```
$ vim -u NONE
:help
" create a manual fold
zf 20j
:set bufhidden=hide
:set buflisted
" navigate to another buffer
:bnext
" navigate back to the help buffer
:bnext
" at this point, there are no manual folds on the help page
```

Using `:mkview` and `:loadview` results in the fold being restored.

Is there some setting that would cause manual folds to be retained in this scenario without requiring the usage of `:mkview` and `:loadview`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily changing `'buftype'` to `<empty>` prevents the folds from being lost.

```
$ vim -u NONE
:help
zf 20j
:set bufhidden=hide
:set buflisted
" temporarily change buftype to <empty>
:set buftype=
:bnext
:bnext
" change buftype back to help
:set buftype=help
```

Setting `'buftype'` back to `help` goes against the warning added in commit [071d427](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/071d4279d6ab81b7187b48f3a0fc61e587b6db6c/runtime/doc/options.txt#L1105) on Jun 13, 2004:

> "you are not supposed to set this manually"

Neovim updated the text in commit [2e1217d](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/2e1217da4617c832afcd7ca90c88b06c200dc23b/runtime/doc/options.txt#L1161) on Nov 10, 2016.

> "do not set this manually"